# Uploading image to server (image corrupt on server)

Tags: java, android

I am trying to upload an image to S3 using a presigned upload URL, which has content type set to `image/jpeg` and method at PUT. Post upload, when I try to access the image on S3, it seems to be corrupt and the size is larger than the local image file. My code is below.

```
        URL url = new URL(uploadUrl);
        HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(httpCon.getOutputStream());

        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile(imagePath, "r");
        int length = (int) imagePath.length();
        byte[] imageData = new byte[length];
        f.readFully(imageData);
        String data = new String(imageData);
        out.write(data);
        out.close();

        int responseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
        return (responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK);
```

Comment: How do you examine that the image is corrupted? And what's the difference in size? Is it possible for this difference to be responsible a different os etc?

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely the corruption occurs when you create a `String` from the image data. From javadoc of the String constructor `String(byte[])`:

> Constructs a new {@code String} by decoding the specified array of
>   bytes using the platform's default charset.  The length of the new
>   {@code String} is a function of the charset, and hence may not be
>   equal to the length of the byte array.

The fix would be to write the byte array directly to the output stream.

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue. I changed my code to directly use the `OutputStream` returned by `HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream` and passed in the `byte[]`.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get similar issue due to some bytes not written yet. I was able to fix it by flushing the output stream.

```
OutputStream out = httpCon.getOutputStream();
....
....
....
....
out.write(imageData);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Hope that helps in your case.